# Kivy:I want to have different buttons and display a different text on pressing each, Is there a way to do so without making a different window?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Let us say I have 4 buttons called 1,2,3,4 and pressing the first I want to display the text one on pressing the second I want to display the text two and so on.

Is there a way to do so without creating new windows for each of the text?

I would prefer to have the code in a kv file.

Comment: Most people are not willing to write code for you. I suggest you write as much code as you can and ask a specific question about why X doesn't work in your code or how to change your code to do Y.

Comment: Just the method is fine. I have explained in the question, 1 way that I know and would like to know if there was an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you asked i made a script to change the label with buttons only
This is my .py file with 4 functions. All it will do is , when you will press the button with corresponding no. the label will also change...  Hope you like it

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.core.text import Text
from kivy.core.text.markup import *
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
import os
import sqlite3 as sql



class Mainscreen(Screen):
    dom = ObjectProperty(None)

    def changeit(self):
        self.dom.text = "1"

    def changeit2(self):
        self.dom.text = "2"

    def changeit3(self):
        self.dom.text = "3"

    def changeit4(self):
        self.dom.text = "4"


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('kv.kv')

class TESTApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TESTApp().run()
```

Now my kivy file (.kv)

```
WindowManager:
    Mainscreen:


<Mainscreen>:

    name: "main"
    dom: change

    Label:
        id: change
        text: "Hello there"
        font_size: 52


    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        size_hint: 0.2,0.2
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'y':0.2}

        Button:
            text: "1"
            on_release: root.changeit()


        Button:
            text: "2"
            on_release: root.changeit2()

        Button:
            text: "3"
            on_release: root.changeit3()

        Button:
            text: "4"
            on_release: root.changeit4()
```

Edit: Like the answer if it helped

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the late reply